# Как получить массив элементов из компонента, находящегося в роутере? Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, компоненты

Есть компонент Header, в который нужно передать массив Items, но сам массив объявляется в компоненте роутера "Menu-edit". Подскажите, как это реализовать?

App.vue

```
<template>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <Header></Header>
        <hr>
        <router-view></router-view>

        <router-link to="/1">1</router-link>
        <router-link to="/2">2</router-link>
        <router-link to="/menu">Menu edit</router-link>
    </div>
</div>
</template>

<script>    
import Header from './Header.vue'

export default {
    components: {
        Header
    },
    data(){
        return {              
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Menu.vue

```
<script>
export default {
    data(){
      return {
          titleItem: '',
          items: [
              {
                  text: 'Hello'
              },  
              {
                  text: 'World'
              },                
            ]
      } 
    },
    methods:{
        addItem(){
            this.items.push({
                text: this.titleItem
            })
        },
        deleteItem: function(index){
            this.items.splice(index, 1)
        }
    },

}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно использовать [vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/ru/) где хранить единое состояние для этих компонентов или можно еще создать глобальный [event bus](https://alligator.io/vuejs/global-event-bus/). Как по мне лучшим решением будет vuex.